Why does Pylance not complain about missing members of a Protocol?
I am using Pylance with vscode and have set the type checking mode to 'strict'
My understanding is that Pylance should flag Bar as not conforming to the Foo Protocol because of the commented foo method in Bar, but it does not.
I if uncomment the line it does correctly complain that 'Method "foo" overrides class "Foo" in an incompatible manner'
Is there something I am missing?
from typing import Protocol
class Foo(Protocol):
  def foo(self, a: str): ...

class Bar(Foo): 
  # def foo(self, b: str): ...
  ...

# The above code generates no errors, however the following line does
a: Foo = Bar() # this generates a 'Cannot instantiate abstract class "Bar"' error in pylance

# but the file does run cleanly

The bottom line here is all I want to do is say that Bar implements Foo and have Pylance tell me if it does not, before I let someone try to create an instance of it.
I am subclassing Foo for 2 reasons.

I want to document that Bar implements the Foo protocol
I want to type check Bar where it is defined rather than when it is instantiated.

I am basing this on part of mypy documentation found here
As I said above, this works fine and flags incorrect method signatures right here in the file defining the Bar class.
The only thing it does not do is flag the missing method.
For that I can add something like the following:
bar: Foo = Bar()
This will highlight the missing method (because the Protocol makes Bar abstract), however it seems hacky to include this in the file defining Bar and also gets complicated if Bar has an __init__ function that takes several argument.
portion of mypy documentation linked above:


In any case, Bar inherits foo from Foo, just as if Foo were not a subclass of Protocol.

updated with more info as to why I am subclassing the protocol class.

It documents that your class implements the protocol. You still have to actually implement it. It's referencing a mypy error, not a runtime error.

I am trying to get the type checker to tell me if I a class I am writing and claiming implements a protocol, actually implements that protocol or not.  It almost works. It finds method signature errors but does not find missing methods.  Pylance does know it's wrong and flags the issue when I try to create an instance.

I found the solution I was looking for here.
Importing final from typing and decorating the class that I expect to implement the full protocol with @final does flag the missing method.
from typing import Protocol, final
class Foo(Protocol):
  def foo(self, a: str): ...

@final
class Bar(Foo):  #pylance error here 
  # def foo(self, b: str): ...
  ...

If I ever actually want to subclass Bar I can just ignore that type error.
class FooBar(Bar): # type: ignore - Bar is only marked final to ensure all protocol members are implemented
  pass


@larsks's answer is partly incorrect: Inheriting a Protocol means to either implement or extend it, depending on whether Protocol itself is used as an explicit base class and whether the abstract members have default implementations.
As for implementing:

To explicitly declare that a certain class implements a given protocol, it can be used as a regular base class. In this case a class could use default implementations of protocol members.
— Protocols § Explicitly declaring implementation | Python typing spec

This does not apply to your example, however, since Foo.foo() does not have a default implementation.
As for extending:

The general philosophy is that protocols are mostly like regular ABCs, but a static type checker will handle them specially. Subclassing a protocol class would not turn the subclass into a protocol unless it also has typing.Protocol as an explicit base class. Without this base, the class is "downgraded" to a regular ABC that cannot be used with structural subtyping.
— Protocols § Merging and extending protocols | Python typing spec

In other words, neither your Bar has Protocol as one of its explicit base classes, nor does it implement the .foo() method, so it is considered an abstract class.
You can verify this by trying to instantiate it:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
Bar()  # error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "Bar"

